# How to avoid BadgedBox get clipped in combination with IconButton

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
IconButton(onClick = onClick) {
        BadgedBox(
            badge = {
                    Badge {
                        Text("2")
                    }
            },
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Notifications,
            )
        }
    }
```

This code leads to this:

[image: BadgedIcon clipped]